# Plotly python scatterplot y axis not ordering

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot, plotly

Plotly.py is having issues with the y axis. Data is not ordered. Even in the csv file the data is sorted in ascending order. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUOL3.png

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

#What is the filename
filename = 'output.csv'
#What is the X Value?
xvalue = 'total_students'
#What is the Y Value?
yvalue = 'realcount'
#What is the plot title?
PlotTitle = 'total_students'

filename = input("What is the filename? (WITH .CSV) ")
xvalue = input("What is the X value? ")
yvalue = input("What is the y Value? ")
PlotTitle = input("What is the title of this chart? ")

esc1 = pd.read_csv('output.csv', encoding='cp1252')
def random_color():
    rgbl=[255,0,0]
    random.shuffle(rgbl)
    return tuple(rgbl)


esc1 = go.Scatter(
    x = esc1[xvalue],
    y = esc1[yvalue],
    name = 'School',
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(
        size = 10,
        sizemode='area',
        sizeref=1,
        color = 'rgba(66, 134, 244, .8)'
    )
)


data = [esc1]

layout = dict(title = 'Total Student Scatter',
              yaxis = dict(zeroline = True,
                title=yvalue),
              xaxis = dict(zeroline = True,
                title=xvalue)
             )

#fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
#py.iplot(fig, filename='styled-scatter')

plotly.offline.plot({
    "data": data,
    "layout": layout
},filename=PlotTitle+'.html', auto_open=False)

print("Finished")
```

Jeeze stack-overflow has a ton of quality control. I have to keep adding details so i hope this helps.

Comment: I dont have enough rep to embed images. Sorry!

Comment: Could you post your code as well?

Comment: @TorinMay Here we go.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have a look at [MCVE]. Without seeing the raw data it is really hard to guess what  is the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, also worked fine. My code:

```
#import all the necessary libraries
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import random
#What is the filename
filename = 'output.csv'
#What is the X Value?
xvalue = 'total_students'
#What is the Y Value?
yvalue = 'realcount'
#What is the plot title?
PlotTitle = 'total_students'

filename = input("What is the filename? (WITH .CSV) ")
xvalue = input("What is the X value? ")
yvalue = input("What is the y Value? ")
PlotTitle = input("What is the title of this chart? ")
esc1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
#I don`t have your `output.csv` so I am created own DataFrame
#esc1 = pd.DataFrame({"total_students":["10","20","30","40","50"],\
#                     "realcount":["8","16","28","39","41"]})
def random_color():
    rgbl=[255,0,0]
    random.shuffle(rgbl)
    return tuple(rgbl)
#That`s your scatter trace 
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = esc1[xvalue],
    y = esc1[yvalue],
    name = 'School',
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(
        size = 10,
        sizemode='area',
        sizeref=1,
        color = 'rgba(66, 134, 244, .8)'
    )
)
#Give trace to data
data = [trace]
#Create layout
layout = dict(title = 'Total Student Scatter',
              yaxis = dict(zeroline = True,
                title=yvalue),
              xaxis = dict(zeroline = True,
                title=xvalue)
             )
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=PlotTitle+'.html', auto_open=False)
print("Finished")
```

And plot looks nice (yaxis and xaxis order as expected):
[image: Works as expected, is not it?]

Comment: @JakeDownie hope my answer help you